# error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [41]'

Tags: c++, function, scope, visibility

I am learning C++ for my Project and I am a beginner. I wrote a simple piece of code to understand scope and visibility of Fucntions and variables.

Here is the code, please help me with this error,

*" error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [41]'"*

Below is the code for my program (written in Visual c++ 2010) :-

```
// scope and visibility.cpp : main project file.

  #include "stdafx.h"

  #include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void myFunction()

{

    cout << "inside myFunction";

    int x= 5;

    cout << "local variable, x :" << x << endl ;
    {
        cout << "inside the very local variable" ;

        int x=10;

        cout << "very local variable, x :" << x << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "inside main function";

    int x = 15;

    cout << "main loop variable, x:" << x << endl;

       myFunction(); 

    cout <"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;

    cin.get();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout <"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;` is the problem. You wrote a single `<`, so the `<<` has higher precedence.

Comment: Typo: `cout <"back to main function loop, variable x :"`

Comment: ('the heck is this getting upvoted?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, and we [close all typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).

Comment: Thankyou so so much. I wasted a hell lot of time in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occured due to a typo. Instead of

```
cout <"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;
    ^^
```

must be

```
cout << "back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;
```

When there is this typo the compiler considers the following part of the expression

```
"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x
```

as an attempt to apply operator << for const char[41] that is the type of the string literal "back to main function loop, variable x :"

Answer (score 0):

Read in main function, at this line:

cout <"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;

may be you forgot a < simbol and should be:

cout <<"back to main function loop, variable x :" << x << endl;

Tell me if works.

Cheers!